# Delta Lake: How to merge with both SCD type 2 and automatic schema evolution enabled?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

The Delta Lake documentation states that to use automatic schema evolution, one has to stick with updateAll() and insertAll() methods when using Delta merge i.e. can't use sub-expressions/conditions to change column values selectively.

https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#automatic-schema-evolution

This is fine until I see the need to run SCD type 2 merges on the same table.

For SCD type 2 I want to be able to 'retire' an existing / matching row and add another one with appropriate flags / dates.

It seems I'm going to have to choose which feature I can have in my etl process using Delta Lake.

Is there an alternative approach which isn't documented? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Will it help to add appropriate flags and dates columns to base schema?

Comment: Should help with SCD merges, how do I do automatic schema evolution with it though?